# Using WebComponents in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-component, polyfills

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and I'm attempting to use the [`WebComponents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) API to load a singleton
customized built-in elements  which represent a modal inhertited from `<div>` loaded in the content script.

My modal custom element looks like this:

```js
// sactModal.ts
export class SactModal extends HTMLDivElement {
  private static instance: SactModal;

  // more private properties

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  // more public methods
}
```

In my `contentScript.ts` I register/define the element and then attempt to add it to the document:

```js
// contentScript.ts
import { SactModal } from "../components/modal/sactModal";

window.customElements.define(
   "sact-modal",
   SactModal,
   { extends: "div" }
);

const modal = document.createElement("sact-modal");
document.body.appendChild(modal);
```

However, I get an error in Chrome dev tools about `customElements` being `undefined`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'define')
```

[image]

So I read up about it and I believe that I'm missing some depenedencies and need to use a polyfill. I believe that the right one that would port the new API into my extension is [`webcomponents`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) So I attempted to use it as instructed:

```bash
npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs
```

And imported it into the `contentScript`:

```js
import "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js";
```

In this case, the `contentScript` doesn't load at all.

I also attempted following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782977/1710131) answer but the `contentScript` doesn't load in this case either...

I'm pretty much at a dead end and will probably need to revert to plain-old JavaScript and use `Document::createElement` to create my custom elements but wanted to know if anyone got this working!

Comment: You can move your script to the page's context where `window.customElements` is defined, [here is how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704/1552587)