# Chrome Extension content script don't load Custom Element via Range.insertNode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, range, web-component, custom-element, content-script

I'm writing a *Chrome Extension* that injects my tiny app into the webpage. My small app was built with *Vue* as a [Custom Element](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue).

I'm bundling the app into one file called `custom-elements.js`, and injecting it alongside my `content.js`:

```json
# manifest.json
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*"],
    "js": [
      "custom-elements.js",
      "content.js"
    ]
  }
],
```

Now, in my extension I'm using the [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) API to hold a reference to a text over elements. My technique is to surround the original text with my **custom element**.

```js
const originalContents = range.extractContents();

const indicator = document.createElement('overlay-indicator');
indicator.appendChild(originalContents);
range.insertNode(indicator);
```

This code produces an empty string. Looking inside the *DevTools*, I see the `shadow-root` is empty (so the original text is there, but it doesn't render because there is no shadow DOM there).

[image: empty shadow root]

I know the **custom element** is working, because if instead of `range.insertNode` I'm using just `appendChild` it renders the **custom element**:

```js
const testIndicator = indicator.cloneNode()
testIndicator.appendChild(originalContents)
const container = range.startContainer;
container.parentElement.insertBefore(testIndicator, container);
```

[image: working shadow dom]

Also, I tried to create an HTML webpage with the `custom-elements.js` imported into it as a script, and there it is working.

#### In summary

It seems using **Custom Element** is working in *Chrome Extension* **content script**, except when using **[`Range.insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode)**.

Comment: Custom elements use js callbacks for lifetime events, but it won't work in a content script by default because they run in an isolated JS world. You can run the code in the [MAIN world](/a/9517879) but it can be hijacked, spoofed, exfiltrated via standard JS prototypes, so I'd suggest not using a custom element at all.

Comment: You cannot use custom element in content_script. Check `console.log(customElements), it is null. Check chrome bug [390807](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390807)

Comment: @Anilkumar @wOxxOm you can see I managed to use `customElements` in a **content script**, so the question is only why it didn't work when I mounted a `customElement` by `Range.insertNode`.

Comment: `customElements` doesn't exist in `content_script`. It is available in popup window and option page.
Why you want to use custom elements ??

Comment: @Anilkumar I well known that you need to add a polyfill to enable `customElements` in `content_script` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782977/839513

Comment: @baruchiro  Can i ask why you want to use custom elements ??

Comment: @Anilkumar I want to inject a small `Vue` app into the page